# How to run the same Python script with 1000 different argument sets on 40 CPUs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I need to run the same script with many different sets of hyperparameters. I have far more sets than CPUs, so I want to do it in parallel, but I want it to schedule one run per CPU. Is there a simple way to do this in Python?

Comment: can you please provide more information about your problem (code) and what you've tried?

Comment: Sure, I rephrased the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65694724/how-to-sweep-many-hyperparameter-sets-in-parallel-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use Python's `multiprocessing` module; in particular you can use `multiprocessing.pool`.

Assuming the work you want to do is encapsulated in a function called `my_function` and the parameters are in `my_iterable`, you can do something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool() as processing_pool:
        processing_pool.map(my_function, my_iterable)
```

Comment: But I need to run it 1000 times, not 40. How would I do that without overburdening the CPUs?

Comment: Also my file isn't a function, it's a python file with parsed arguments. Can I pass a file into multiproc?